# Creating tab spaces in word document using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I am using Apche POI to create MS Word documents(.docx format). I am able to create custom spaces among lines of text. Is there any class that is used to **create tab spaces in word** documents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you able to use a character run to insert a \t character?  I haven't tested this but it should work as follows:

```
      XWPFDocument newDoc = new XWPFDocument(); //Doc to write new doc to
      XWPFParagraph para = newDoc.createParagraph(); //Paragraph
      XWPFRun run = para.createRun();  //Where the text will be written from
      run.setText("\t");
```

**EDIT**

The alternative is to 'simulate' the tab yourself, I have tested this bit and it does work:

```
run.setText("     ");
```

Comment: Are you using an XWPFRun to create your document?  Or are you doing it another way/

Comment: @MaheshVarma I have added a small edit to my answer, I could not find a way to insert a tab so I simulated the effect instead.  It worked for me, so please see if it works for you

Answer (score 6):

```
CTR ctr = run.getCTR();
ctr.addNewTab();
run.setText("abcd");
```

i tested.

Answer (score 2):

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#addTab()

```
XWPFDocument newDoc = new XWPFDocument(); //Doc to write new doc to
XWPFParagraph para = newDoc.createParagraph(); //Paragraph
XWPFRun run = para.createRun();  //Where the text will be written from
run.addTab()//Add tab and after that you can set text.
run.setText("Your text here...");
```

If you want to have [*text **tab** text*] just create two runs then add `addTab()` after `setText()` first or before `setText()` second

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the first part of the text to your `run`, then call `run.addTab();` and finally add the text which comes after the tab.